# Slow svn up, ci, etc

Tags: ssh, svn, fstab

I have a server (LAN) and a few projects subverion.
They (developers) tell me that is running very slow (update, checkout, etc)

They use svn+ssh://

```
server:/# svnserve --version
svnserve, version 1.5.1 (r32289)
   compiled Aug  6 2009, 16:55:38

server:/# cat /etc/debian_version 
5.0.3
```

fstab

```
/dev/storage/svn /svn ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,auto,nouser,async,noatime 0 1
```

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume "they" are developers? :)

Is the svn server on the local LAN?

I had a similar problem recently, using svn over https (with apache).

"They" asked for the default svnserve daemon to be enabled to test, and it turned out to be only a little quicker.

I think you have to go back to your devs and ask what kinds of operations they are trying to do. Look at how the repo is organised and try to work out if it could be organised better. Don't be afraid to ask questions.

It might be worth testing svn+ssh vs. svnserve vs. svn/https. Or go crazy and install git.

Comment: > I presume "they" are developers? :)
Yes :P

> Is the svn server on the local LAN?
YES! :D

I well be try svn/https

Comment: heh, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Subversion has always been known to be *very* slow, esp. on big repos.

Comment: When a repository is big ?